# Iterate over grouped rows Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have a dataframe like this

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [912665, 455378, 938724, 557830
                         ],
                    "NAME": ["Anna","Anna","Diana","Peter"
                            ],
                    "LAST_NAME": ["Johns","Johns","Scott","Scott"
                            ], 

                   "ADDRESS": ["Address1","Address2","Address3","Address3"],     
                   "PHONE": ['0000000001','0000000001','0000000002','0000000002' 
                        ],
                   "ngroup": [0, 0,1,1]}

                      )

df_test
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzjE7.png)

There are two groups in column ngroup - 0 and 1

Within each group I would like to do a comparison between some columns like NAME, LAST_NAME, ADDRESS and give a new column called Rate which gives me a score based on whether those rows are the same or not.

For example

1. for group 0 we could get a Rate like:
   5 (because Names are the same) + 30 (because Last names are the same) + 0 (because addresses are not the same) + 50 (because phones are the same) = 85
2. For group 1:
   0 + 30 + 15 + 30 = 75

What is the best way to iterate over these rows and get a new column Rate and add it to the current dataframe? 
I was trying some different things, but can't get any working solution for now.

Comment: Are there always two names/addresses in a group?

Comment: @Dave not necessarily, It could be three or more.

Comment: Where does `15` come from you have 50 in your list above?

Comment: @Datanovice it's just for example. It could be any number to sum for a rate.

Comment: How does your formula work if there are three names and only two match? What's the difference between, say, 2 of 5 matching and 4 of 5?

Comment: @Dave for simplicity let's say that there are only two rows within each group now, because for many rows it would not work this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is no need to **iterate** over group rows.

The task is rather to **apply** a function calculating the rate for each group.

The first component needed is a lambda function, to be applied to each column
in a group (a *Numpy* 1-D array), checking whether all elements are the same.
Actually, it checks whether element *0* is equal to all elements starting
from *1* and returns *1* (as *True*) or *0* as (*False*).

```
lambda v: (v[0] == v[1:]).all().astype(int)
```

Then the concept is to:

- `grp.values` - convert the current group to a *Numpy* array.
- `[:, 1:-1]` - drop the first (*ID*) and last (*ngroup*) column.
- `apply_along_axis(...)` - apply the above function to each remaining
  column. Argument *0* is the axis number (apply the function to each
  column slice). The result is a vector of ones or zeroes.
- `... * [5, 30, 15, 50]` - multiply the above vector by weights for each
  column, getting column ratings.
- `np.sum(...)` - sum them, getting the overall group rate.

The code to do it is:

```
def getRate(grp):
    return np.sum(np.apply_along_axis(lambda v: (v[0] == v[1:]).all().astype(int),
        0, grp.values[:, 1:-1]) * [5, 30, 15, 50])
```

Then apply the above function to each group:

```
df_test.groupby('ngroup').apply(getRate)
```

The result is:

```
ngroup
0    85
1    95
dtype: int64
```

Note that the result for group *1* is `0 * 5 + 1 * 30 + 1 * 15 + 1 * 50 = 95`,
not *75* as in your post, because the weight for *PHONE* column is **50**
(see point 1 of your example).

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can create a rate dictionary with the name of your columns, then `stack` and `map` your values whilst only summing the duplicate values.

```
rates = {'NAME' : 5, 'LAST_NAME' : 30, 'ADDRESS' : 0 ,'PHONE' : 50 }

s = df.groupby('ngroup').agg(list).stack().explode().duplicated().to_frame()


s['vals'] = s.index.get_level_values(1).map(rates)


s[s[0].eq(True)].groupby(level=0).sum()

          0   vals
ngroup            
0       3.0   85.0
1       4.0  130.0
```